# How to receive data from SELECT-OPTION

Tags: html

When I'll use in the php form this code

```
    <option value="foo|bar">foo</option>
```

than how to receive the part 'foo' and the part 'bar'?

Comment: what do you mention saying 'to recieve' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your select tag has the name `mySelect`, you can assign them to the array `$split_values` in php using

```
$split_values = explode("|", $POST_["mySelect"]);
```

You can then access the foo part with `$split_values[0]` and the bar part with `$split_values[1]`.

Comment: thnks, i like simple php solutions. brgs

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean, but something like `"foo|bar".split('|')[0]`?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with assignment `id` to option tag and:

```
<option id="test" value="foo|bar">foo</option>
```

some javascript code:

```
var option_val = document.getElementById('test').value;
alert(option_val.split('|', 2));
```